# Python: Incorrect index after group by with different aggregation to set of columns

Tags: pandas, indexing, filter, group-by, aggregate

I would like to group by `CurrentDate, Car` fields and apply the following functions:

1. `np.mean` function to list of `['Attr1',...'Attr5']` columns;
2. `np.random` for `Factory` column;

Example of `df` is introduced there:

```
Index   Car       Attr1    Attr2  Attr3  Attr4  Attr5  AttrFactory  CurrentDate                           
0      Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8      F1          01/07/18
1      Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8      F2          01/07/18
2      Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8      F3          03/08/18
3      Porsche    10.0      0.0    2.8    3.5    6.5      F2          05/08/18
4      Porsche    10.0      2.0    0.8    3.5    6.5      F1          05/08/18   
5      Golf       0.0       1.7    3.0    2.0    6.3      F4          07/09/18       
6      Tiguan     1.0       0.0    3.0    5.2    5.8      F5          10/09/18         
7      Porsche    0.0       0.0    3.0    4.2    7.8      F4          12/09/18     
8      Tiguan     0.0       0.0    0.0    7.2    9.0      F3          13/09/18    
9      Golf       0.0       3.0    0.0    0.0    4.8      F5          25/09/18 
10     Golf       0.0       3.0    0.0    0.0    4.8      F1          25/09/18  
11     Golf       0.0       3.0    0.0    0.0    4.8      F3          25/09/18
```

I tried to do it by the following code:

```
metric_cols = df.filter(regex='^Attr',axis=1).columns #it's list of all Attr columns;

addt_col = list(df.filter(regex='^Attr',axis=1).columns).remove('AttrFactory')


df_gr = df.groupby(['CurrentDate', 'Car'], as_index=False)[metric_cols].agg({addt_col: np.mean, 'AttrFactory': lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.choice(range(0,len(x)))]})
```

In result I received `df` with inctorrect index:

```
CurrentDate     Car          NaN
                         CurrentDate   Car    Attr1  Attr2  Attr3  Attr4  Attr5 AttrFactory                           
01/07/18      Nissan       01/07/18   Nissan    0.0   1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8      F1                   
03/08/18      Nissan       03/08/18   Nissan    0.0   1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8      F3          
05/08/18      Porsche      05/08/18   Porsche   10.0  1.0    1.8    3.5    6.5      F1                    
  ...           ...         ...        ...      ...   ...    ...    ...    ...      ...  
13/09/18      Tiguan       13/09/18   Tiguan    0.0   0.0    0.0    7.2    9.0      F3          
25/09/18      Golf         25/09/18   Golf      0.0   1.0    0.0    0.0    4.8      F3
```

Expected output is `df_gr`:

```
                           Attr1  Attr2  Attr3  Attr4  Attr5  AttrFactory                           
01/07/18      Nissan        0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8       F1                   
03/08/18      Nissan        0.0    1.7    3.7    0.0    6.8       F3          
05/08/18      Porsche       10.0   1.0    1.8    3.5    6.5       F1                    
  ...         ...           ...    ...    ...    ...    ...       ...      
13/09/18      Tiguan        0.0    0.0    0.0    7.2    9.0       F3          
25/09/18      Golf          0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    4.8       F3
```

How can I fix the `CurrentDate  Car   Nan` incorrect index at the top of result? 
I'd appreciate for any idea, thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dictionary of your aggregations and pass them into agg

IN:

```
metric_cols = df.filter(regex='^Attr\d',axis=1).columns 

d = dict.fromkeys(metric_cols, ['mean'])
d['AttrFactory'] = lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.choice(range(0,len(x)))]

df = df.groupby(['CurrentDate', 'Car'], as_index=False).agg(d).droplevel(1, axis=1)
```

OUT:

```
|   | CurrentDate | Car     | Attr1 | Attr2 | Attr3              | Attr4 | Attr5 | AttrFactory |
|---|-------------|---------|-------|-------|--------------------|-------|-------|-------------|
| 0 | 01/07/18    | Nissan  | 0.0   | 1.7   | 3.7                | 0.0   | 6.8   | F2          |
| 1 | 03/08/18    | Nissan  | 0.0   | 1.7   | 3.7                | 0.0   | 6.8   | F3          |
| 2 | 05/08/18    | Porsche | 10.0  | 1.0   | 1.7999999999999998 | 3.5   | 6.5   | F1          |
| 3 | 07/09/18    | Golf    | 0.0   | 1.7   | 3.0                | 2.0   | 6.3   | F4          |
| 4 | 10/09/18    | Tiguan  | 1.0   | 0.0   | 3.0                | 5.2   | 5.8   | F5          |
| 5 | 12/09/18    | Porsche | 0.0   | 0.0   | 3.0                | 4.2   | 7.8   | F4          |
| 6 | 13/09/18    | Tiguan  | 0.0   | 0.0   | 0.0                | 7.2   | 9.0   | F3          |
| 7 | 25/09/18    | Golf    | 0.0   | 3.0   | 0.0                | 0.0   | 4.8   | F1          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregators are being applied column-wise and therefore are stored in level 2 while the column names are stored in level 1 *(to prevent overwriting)*. This is especially useful when applying multiple aggregators per column.

A solution for this would be the following:

```
# Merge the aggregator with the column name
df_gr.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df_gr.columns.values.reshape(-1)]
```